# Enable DelegateCommand

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button

Little puzzled

If i have a button in a wpf window and bind it to a DelegateCommand

```
<Button Grid.Row="1"  Content="Remove" Command="{Binding CommandDelete }" />
```

And in my simple viewmodel i attach

```
CommandDelete = new DelegateCommand<string>(OnDeleteExecute, OnDeleteCanExecute);
```

If the button is to be enabled when i choose an item from a list i can bind the list selecteditem to property in my viewmodel

```
Report selectedReport;
            public Report SelectedReport
            {
                get { return this.selectedReport ;}
                set { this.selectedReport = value;}
            }
private bool OnDeleteCanExecute(string commandParameter)
            {
                return (this.selectedReport != null);
            }
```

This seems fine to me so far and the only thing missing is to raise a CanExecute event for the specific button in the setter for SelectedReport

```
CommandDelete.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
```

This works but my question is if i have 10 button do i need to call RaiseCanExecuteChanged for each and every button each time a item is selected or is there as smarter way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually I place my `RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` in the `PropertyChanged` event for that class.

For example, if `DeleteCommand.CanExecute` is based on the `SelectedReport` property, I'll hook into the `PropertyChanged` event of the `ViewModel` and raise the `CanExecuteChanged` event anytime `SelectedReport` changes.

```
void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "SelectedReport")
        DeleteCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

This keeps all the logic in one central place and ensures the `CanExecuteChanged` gets raised whenever one of the parameters changes.

The other alternative is to switch from using a `DelegateCommand` to a `RelayCommand`, which automatically raise it's `CanExecuteChanged` when a property changes. I would assume there's a performance difference, however have never noticed one.

Comment: Thanks , implemented it and works like a charm. Keeeps the code a little cleaner